# How to stop Neo4J Cypher from processing an empty collection?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have this kind of request Cypher Neo4J request:

```
MATCH (c1:Concept) 
WHERE  c1.name in (['word']) 
WITH COLLECT(distinct c1) as concepts 
MATCH (ctx:Context) 
WHERE ALL(c in concepts 
       WHERE (c)-->(ctx) AND ((ctx.by) = '15229100-b20e-11e3-80d3-6150cb20a1b9')) 
RETURN ctx
```

If there is a `c1` with the `name` `word`, then it gets processed fine and I get acceptable results.

However, if there's no `c1` with `word` then an empty collection is returned, however, it gets further processed and I just get all the `ctx:Context` nodes that satisfy the `ctx.by` criteria. Which is not right.

How to fix that in the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregations (alone, without any non-aggregation variables as grouping keys) will succeed even when there are no rows, emitting a single row with the result, which will allow further processing, since there is a row to operate on.

To get the behavior you want, add a filter after the aggregation to ensure you have a non-empty list. This will ensure that if the list is empty, rows go to 0 and the subsequent operations won't take place:

```
MATCH (c1:Concept) 
WHERE  c1.name in (['word']) 
WITH COLLECT(distinct c1) as concepts 
WHERE size(concepts) <> 0
MATCH (ctx:Context) 
WHERE ALL(c in concepts 
       WHERE (c)-->(ctx) AND ((ctx.by) = '15229100-b20e-11e3-80d3-6150cb20a1b9')) 
RETURN ctx
```

Comment: Beautiful! It worked! Thank you! But I don't understand the logic: if the returned aggregation has no rows, why does it trigger the subsequent query and why does it get further processed?

Comment: Aggregations on their own succeed when there are no rows. A `count()` being performed over no rows will emit a row with `0`. A `collect()` over no rows (as in your case) emits a row with an empty list. (and as long as there's a row to operate on, subsequent operations will take place) These are necessary in several cases. Consider a very complex query with lots of filtering that eventually results in no rows, with a RETURN involving a count() or a collect() or similar aggregation. We need to properly return that count of 0 or that empty list.